# Conan error - settings.os.subsystem value not defined

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm following the [conan 2 tutorial](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html) on consuming packages. Everything works in Linux, but when using a Windows system I get :

```
ERROR: There are invalid packages:
zlib/1.2.13: Invalid: 'settings.os.subsystem' value not defined
```

my default profile was generated as per the tutorial:

```
conan profile detect --force
```

After adding `settings.os.subsystem='msys2'` in my profile (at least that's what googling around got me to) the error mutates to:

```
ERROR: There are invalid packages:
zlib/1.2.13: Invalid: 'settings.arch' value not defined
```

This "whack-a-mole" doesn't feel right so I'm wondering whether I'm doing something wrong. That's the official tutorial and the [zlib package](https://conan.io/center/recipes/zlib?version=1.2.13) is supposed to be there for windows. So where is the problem?

---

For completeness, I should mention that fixing all problems like those mentioned above (essentially settings errors) ends up giving a different kind of error:

```
*********************************************************
Recipe 'zlib/1.2.13' cannot build its binary
It is possible that this recipe is not Conan 2.0 ready
If the recipe comes from ConanCenter, report it at https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues 
If it is your recipe, check if it is updated to 2.0
*********************************************************

ERROR: zlib/1.2.13: Error in build() method, line 84
        cmake.configure()
        ConanException: Error 1 while executing
```

but at this point I can't know if this is the fault of me filling in profile information.

Comment: Try compiling with Visual Studio (Community if license allows you to do this). I tried to build the boost with the mingw64 yesterday and failed also. I'm not sure anyone is testing on Windows on msys2/mingw. They rather use VS.

Comment: Vast majority of Conan users use VS in Windows. ``msys2`` works, and many recipes in ConanCenter (all those GNU-like autotools-based libraries) build using an ``msys2`` bash (but with VS compiler), via a ``msys2/...`` tool-requires. It is very likely that the build system of many ConanCenter packages is not prepared to be compiled in ``msys2`` subsystem, so not necessarily a Conan issue, but a recipe issue.

Comment: Defining settings in profile like ``settings.os.subsystem='msys2'`` is not configuring or setting-up the actual environment, but just a declaration of the binary compatibility of the resulting binaries. Correctly setting up the environment still needs to be done. If you really need binaries for ``msys2`` subsystem, I'd suggest to use Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan for support.